# Evaluating only particular Head type in expression?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I remember seeing a recipe to take an expression and evaluate every Head that matches pattern x, while leaving subexpressions with non-matching heads unevaluated. I can't find this recipe anymore, does anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is from [Ted Ersek's Mathematica Tricks under "Clever Little Programs"](http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/HTMLLinks/Tricks_Misc_1.html).
Thanks to *@TomD* for the pointer.

```
EvaluatePattern[expr_,pattn_]:=expr/.Pattern[p, pattn]:>With[{eval=p},eval/;True]

In[368]:= test = HoldForm[7 (1 + 2 - 2^2) (8 + 8)];
          EvaluatePattern[test, _Plus] //InputForm

Out[369]= HoldForm[7*-1*16]
```

**Edit**

It seems to work also with Hold[], but I never ran a deep test.

Comment: This is discussed in Ted Ersek's Mathematica Tricks under "Clever Little Programs".  http://www.verbeia.com/mathematica/tips/Tricks.html